# How to create custom navigation drawer which opens ListView adjacent to drawer onitemclick?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, navigation-drawer

I have created simple navigation drawer but when i came across navigation drawer like in image i am stuck . I have no idea how to achieve this kind of functionality.

[image]

Here in this image "City" is item of navigation drawer and when i click on city it opens list just adjacent to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are COMPLETE CODES , because i do not know details it may not really meet your requirements:

first i like to show demo:

[image]

string.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">NavigationDrawer</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

    <string-array name="left">
        <item name="1">1</item>
        <item name="2">2</item>
        <item name="3">3</item>
    </string-array>


    <string-array name="right1">
        <item name="1*1">1*1</item>
        <item name="1*2">1*2</item>
        <item name="1*3">1*3</item>
        <item name="1*4">1*4</item>
        <item name="1*5">1*5</item>
        <item name="1*6">1*6</item>
        <item name="1*7">1*7</item>
        <item name="1*8">1*8</item>
        <item name="1*9">1*9</item>
    </string-array>


    <string-array name="right2">
        <item name="2*1">2*1</item>
        <item name="2*2">2*2</item>
        <item name="2*3">2*3</item>
        <item name="2*4">2*4</item>
        <item name="2*5">2*5</item>
        <item name="2*6">2*6</item>
        <item name="2*7">2*7</item>
        <item name="2*8">2*8</item>
        <item name="2*9">2*9</item>
    </string-array>


    <string-array name="right3">
        <item name="3*1">3*1</item>
        <item name="3*2">3*2</item>
        <item name="3*3">3*3</item>
        <item name="3*4">3*4</item>
        <item name="3*5">3*5</item>
        <item name="3*6">3*6</item>
        <item name="3*7">3*7</item>
        <item name="3*8">3*8</item>
        <item name="3*9">3*9</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

and MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.navigationdrawer;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.DrawerListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private ListView leftList;
    private ListView rightList;
    private String[] leftListStrings;
    private String[] rightListStrings;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        leftList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_list);
        rightList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_list);
        rightList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        leftListStrings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.left);

        leftList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,leftListStrings));

        leftList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {


                arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                if(arg2 == 0){

                    rightListStrings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.right1);

                    List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(rightListStrings);

                    rightList.setAdapter(new MayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringList));
                    rightList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                if(arg2 == 1){

                    rightListStrings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.right2);
                    List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(rightListStrings);

                    rightList.setAdapter(new MayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringList));
                    rightList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                if(arg2 == 2){

                    rightListStrings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.right3);
                    List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(rightListStrings);

                    rightList.setAdapter(new MayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringList));
                    rightList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }

        });

        drawer.setDrawerListener(new DrawerListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View arg0, float arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                rightList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });


    }

 class MayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    List<String> myList = null;
    public MayAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource,  objects);
        myList = objects;
    }
    public List<String> getMyList() {
        return myList;
    }
    public void setMyList(List<String> myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
    }    
 }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

and layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.navigationdrawer.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="240dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Hello" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_list"
            android:layout_width="120dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#00FF00"
            android:divider="#FFFFFF"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp" >
        </ListView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/right_list"
            android:layout_width="120dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:divider="#FFFFFF"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: @Deep Shah it has just a bug that i did not go to detail for it and that is in the left list when an item selected the color dose not change back to green. this is not really hard to fix and i think you can do it by your own, i just want to show the main idea!!

Comment: i show it but i can solve it. i only need to know how to do it because i have dynamic data so just have to create custom adapter to display it . thanks

Comment: @Deep Shah. i know the solution but i'd rather you just ask it on SO ;-) i and others will answer it definitely. and also i want to know people's solution and you may get better answer than mine. this way also other googlers may find their answers easily

Answer (score 0):

In your sliding menu, I think you need to use expandable listview. 
[This](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) is reference for you. 
Hope for help.

Comment: i have also created expandable listview in navigation drawer but not getting this UI. this is something else.