# Trying to accomplish this UI layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following screen layout I am trying to put together for my android app.

[image]

(excuse the pathetic paint job :) )

When the user clicks on the left hand navigation, they will get the page for that to display on the right.

I'm wondering, do I need to use fragments to get this right ? 
I can't seem to get the correct layout - whether its linear/relative/grid to look as such.
If anyone has similar layout XML, it would be a great help kick-starting this UI for me.

thx

Comment: what is the details part gonna display? A whole new UI or just a listView changing data??

Comment: yeh just a listview with small amount of details

Comment: cool, then i would go only for a single fragment with a linear layout in the left for displaying `A`, `B`, `C` and a listview on the right side. Now on each click on `A`,`B` or `C`. just change the adapter tied to  the listview and notify it. :-/

Comment: It is sliding menu Drawer. [Check](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) This out.

Comment: hope my question helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321168/how-to-create-custom-navigation-drawer-which-opens-listview-adjacent-to-drawer-o

Comment: thx Dhaval , yes its kind of like that, but i prefer the left hand navigation to stay open, and it shows which page they are on - thx though I will look into the navigation drawer

Comment: @makapaka it will stay open in tablate, in phone you need to do some modification in that tutorial.

Comment: and why can't this be done with 3 normal buttons?

Comment: @BartHofma maybe it can - but what i'm having most trouble with is getting the layout correct where the right side takes up the entire height of the left hand side

Comment: @Panther thx but how do I get the right side to span the whole of the left side ?

Comment: trying to build you an example, now i see what you're running into... should be possible though, but didnt figure it out yet

Comment: check out panthers answer, it works :)

Answer (score 3):

My layout for this would go like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="70.0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <!-- Control the width as you like -->
     <!-- Add your A ,B, c Layouts here -->
   </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```